# in php why does isn't work

Tags: php, class, extends

```
class GrandClass {
    public $data;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->someMethodInTheParentClass();
    }
    public function someMethodInTheParentClass() {
        $this->$data = 123456;
    }
}

class MyParent extends GrandClass{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Child extends MyParent {
    // public $data;
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function getData() {
        return $this->data; 
    }
}

$a = new Child();
var_dump($a->getData());
```

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: data in D:\test.php on line 7

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access empty property in D:\test.php on line 7

Comment: use $this->data not $this->$data

Comment: $this->data instead of $this->$data

Comment: $this->$data = 123456; change to $this->data = 123456;

Comment: 전창한  check the comments and  answers and mark one as accepted.thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

update your function  someMethodInTheParentClass with below using $this->data = 123456;

```
 public function someMethodInTheParentClass() {
        $this->data = 123456;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Use  `$this->data = 123456; `instead of`  $this->$data = 123456;` in below function

public function someMethodInTheParentClass() {
        $this->data = 123456;
}
```

Comment: You might wanna flesh out your answer a little if you can, and perhaps format your answer a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

Constructors in MyParent and Child classes are unnecessary.